# How to test flash memory

Tags: flash, eeprom

I'm using blackfin533, and I would like to write a software for flash memory testing. How would I test the flash memory ? I know how to test an eeprom but how would I test the flash memory of the blackfin533?

Comment: Test for what? That flash is in there? That it contains expected information?

Comment: that the flash is there, and it contains information. but I don't know how to write it in using C code. how to access it

Comment: The blackfin 533 processor has no internal flash memory, so you must have a board with _external_ flash on it, right? Which board, and what OS are you running?

Comment: yes, I'm using an external flash, correct. I'm using that flash ST M29W800D. Would you direct me on how to verify that the flash is working ? steps to do ? the datasheet is not valuable

Comment: I will be honest.  Most of us use a driver provided by the processor's manufacturer to abstract the difficulties of managing flash memory.  It sounds like you need to do a lot of research / education if you do not realize this.  Especially if you are going to implement the code to manage flash memory your self.  Searching on "ST M29W800D" I found the chip's specifications right away.  You need to read about how long it takes to do a write, what a block is & how to erase parts of the flash's memory.

Comment: I already have a driver for the external flash memory. what are the steps procedures for testing the external flash memory if its ok or not

Comment: should I erase it then fill it with data and read the data back, or should I fill it with data then read the data back, but If I overwrite it, I will destroy the software that is running. I don't know how to test its functionality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps for testing external flash memory](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262886/steps-for-testing-external-flash-memory)

Answer (score 0):

Normally applications do not test flash memory as normal flash memory has a limited number of guaranteed write cycles.

The normal practice, if data validation is necessary, is to write a set of data followed by a [check sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).  The specific type of check sum does not matter as long as it satisfies your requirements.  They all should be able to tell if a single bit has unexpectedly changed.  More complex check sums can also correct for these unexpected changes.

Added later...

I see from the comments the intent is to use an Analog.com's Blackfin processor to access external flash memory.  Perhaps [this document](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE-302.pdf) will help you develop the code to manage this type of memory.

Comment: how would I access and write the data to the flash eeprom

Comment: This could be a very broad question.  Are you sure you want to write to the processor's flash memory?  In many applications, the flash memory is used only for program storage.  If you are not careful, writing to flash memory may corrupt your program's execution.  Of course Analog's BlackFin processor may have reserved some flash for data storage.  You would have to dive into the processors specifications to understand what Analog's intentions were.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are writing to external flash memory.